# Making an inline quote indicator in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have a document with a large number of items I need to respond with line-by-line. I am able to create block quotes using the indent function, but I would like to put a bar as a prefix for each line, similar to what is done for block quotes in Gmail or [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/174406/how-do-i-get-that-nice-inline-quote-indicator-in-outlook-2010-when-replying-to-e) for Outlook.

I can sort of do this by inserting a shape within the indent of each text block, but I am trying to figure out if there is a way to set up Word to do this automatically.

Comment: Do I get the question right: you have document that contains multiple paragraphs/questions that are formatted with the "Normal" style. Now you want to insert a new paragraph after each question and that new paragraph should start with a block character? Do you want this paragraph to also be formatted in any specific way (e.g. indent, color, etc.)? Should there be any gap between the block character and your response (e.g. tab, space, etc.)? What exact charcter do you have in mind for the block character?

Comment: If you are quoting a quote, do you need 2 quote shapes at the beginning of the para., and so on, as in the Outlook question that you reference?

Comment: @Loeli I'd prefer to have a single bar on the left side that spans the height of the block quoted paragraph, as is possible using the inline quote function in Gmail

Comment: @user2352714 in that case, the provided solution from Charles seems like the best way to go. The left paragraph border will span from the top of the quote to the end of the quote and you can even customize that line (thickness, color, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create an Inline Quote paragraph style with a left border.

1. Base it on your regular Body Text style.
2. You want your custom style to have a left paragraph border. This gives you your line. You will want sufficient padding for the border and may want a hanging indent.
3. Set the indents for your quoted text.
4. Attach a keyboard shortcut to it.
5. Set the style's setting for style for following paragraph to be your Body Text style.

**References:**

- [Modify/Create a Style](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm#ModifyStyle) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- My article on [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330)
- My page on [the Importance of Styles in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm)